# WatchOS template Missing in Xamarin studio on Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

WatchOS template is missing from my xamarin studio on Mac. I cannot create any watchOS app because of this. I have tried to install xamarin.ios.9.3 but nothing comes up. please help

Comment: refer this : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/watch/getting-started/installation/

Comment: yeah.. i have tried that as well. but still not visible

Comment: you have to first create   `IosApp`. Then add new project it will display your `WatchOS` template. Now do it.